# The array won't work with the output of my pictures

Tags: javascript, html

I tried to show pictures with an array so I can change it per delay, kinda like a slideshow. The problem is, that only the first picture will load. when the counter of the array changes, the picture won't load.

The paths of the images are all correct

```
<!DOCTYPE html>`enter code here`
<html lang="en">
<head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test2</title>
    <script>

        var bilder = []; 
        var zeit = 3000;
        var p = 0;

        bilder[0] = "../Bilder/Bild1.jpg";
        bilder[1] = "../Bilder/Bild2.jpg";
        bilder[2] = "../Bilder/Bild3.jpg";
        bilder[3] = "../Bilder/Bild4.jpg";

        function BildAutoWeiter()
        {
            document.bild.src = bilder[p]; 
            for( var i=0; i<= bilder.length; i++)                              
            {
                if(i <= bilder.length)
                {
                     p++;
                }
                else
                {
                    i = 0;
                }
            }
            setTimeout("BildAutoWeiter()", zeit);                       
        }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="BildAutoWeiter()">
<div>
    <img name ="bild" width="100%" height="50%">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You don't pass a string to `setTimeout`, just `setTimeout(BildAutoWeiter, zeit);`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to use `getElementsByName()` to choose elements by their `name=''`. That returns an array of elements that use that `name`, so to choose a specific one, use an index `[index]` starting from 0. Do this instead:

```
document.getElementsByName('bild')[0].src = bilder[p];
```

That selects the first element that uses `name='bild'`

Also, the `for` statement is a bit useless. You could instead do:

```
function BildAutoWeiter()
{
  document.bild.src = bilder[p];
  p++;
  setTimeout(BildAutoWeiter, zeit);
}
```

You don't need to put the function name in quotations and you can't have the parentheses while calling the function in `setTimeout`.

Comment: actually it works quite well with the method i used. When I change it to yours it's still the same result

Comment: @CoreIce I found another error in your code, I'm editing my answer right now :) Also, [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName) says you need to use that selector.

Comment: @CoreIce I added your other error into this answer :)